# Could not find the task 'tsc: build - tsconfig.json' in Linux Mint

Tags: typescript, debugging

[image: Error Message that i become as photo]

I keep receiving the following error message consistently:

**'Could not find the task 'tsc: build - tsconfig.json'**,

whenever I attempt to debug TypeScript code. Despite searching for solutions and consulting other questions, I haven't found a resolution. Below is a depiction of how my debug files are configured:

**.vscode>launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/index.ts",
            "preLaunchTask": "tsc: build - tsconfig.json",
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**/*.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**.vscode>tasks.json**

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {           
            "label": "tsc: build - tsconfig.json",
            "type": "typescript",
            "tsconfig": "src/tsconfig.json",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$tsc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
        }
    ]
}
```

How my file path seems like:
[File path as photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Du8Sd.png)

- I have verified that both the launch.json and tasks.json files exist in the correct path, and I have checked for any typos.
- I have confirmed that the TypeScript compiler (tsc) is present in the $PATH environment variable.
- I have installed TypeScript globally using the command npm install -g typescript.
- Additionally, I have explored similar questions on Stack Overflow, but none of the suggested solutions have resolved the issue.